# Why opening application with shortcut doesn't behave the same as opening it from the dock

Tags: macos, applications, automator, shortcuts-app

I want to open an application (Zotero) with a shortcut in the same way it opens when I click on it in the dock. When I open it from the dock the application recalls the previous changes (window size, position etc.), but if I open it with a shortcut it gets reset to a default each time I use the shortcut.

I have tried both Automator (Launch Application) and Keyboard Maestro (I have tried both "Activate a Specific Application" and "Open Application").

Most puzzling, if I try the `run` (Automator) or `try` (KB) function, the application opens as if clicked in the dock. Could someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: **Zotero** always opens the same for me no matter how I open it. That said, if you have its **Dock Tile** set to always show in the **Dock**, then here's the **AppleScript** _code_ to click the app's **Dock Tile**: `tell application "System Events" to click (every UI element of list 1 of application process "Dock" whose name is "Zotero")` Does that help any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! I have received another solution which works as expected (as if the app was opened from the dock): I have created an AppleScript with `activate application "Zotero"`. I still don't understand why the Launch Application behaves differently.